# Error EOF using pscp to transfer files to windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, scp, pscp

I am using pscp to transfer files from my computer to a windows server but it doesn't work.

here is the command I'm using and the result

```
pscp -v -scp file_test.txt LOGIN@HOST_ADDRESS:C:.\

Looking up host "HOST_ADDRESS"
Connecting to IP_ADDRESS port 22
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.63
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa *******************************************
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
Using username "LOGIN".
Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
LOGIN@HOST_ADDRESS's password:
Sent password
Access granted
Opening session as main channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
Using SCP1
Connected to HOST_ADDRESS
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Sent EOF message
```

And then nothing.
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Why the "C:.\"?

Comment: I tried many possibilites for the destination folder, this is just an exemple

Answer (score -1):

Your login shell is likely returning output, which breaks scp.